# SQL Find Possible Duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates

I need SQL code that will identify possible duplicates in a table. Lets say my table has 4 columns:

- ID (primary key)
- Date1
- Date2
- GroupID

(Date1, Date2, GroupID) form a unique key.

This table gets populated with blocks of data at a time, and it often happens that a new block is loaded in that contains a number of records that are already in there. This fine as long as the unique key catches them. Unfortunately, sometimes Date1 is empty (or at least '1900/01/01') either with the first or subsequent uploads.

So what I need is something to identify where the (Date2, GroupID) combination appear more than once and where for **one** of the records Date1 = '1900/01/01'

Thanks

Karl

Comment: If you have multiple entries with Date1 being 1900/01/01, and Date2 and GroupID the same, is it considered multiple? I would guess it is...

Comment: in that case it wouldn't be a problem - only becomes a problem if Date1 is 1900/01/01 in one upload but has a value in another one

Comment: I meant if you have multiple entries with Date1 being 1900/01/01, and Date2 and GroupID the same, but one Date1 does have value (with the same Date2 and GroupID).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bkm kind of has it, but the inner select can perform poorly on some databases.
This is more straightforward:

```
select t1.* from 
t as t1 left join t as t2 
on (t1.date2=t2.date2 and t1.groupid=t2.groupid)
where t1.id != t2.id and (t1.date1='1900/01/01' or t2.date2='1900/01/01')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can identify duplicates on (date2, GroupID) using

```
Select date2,GroupID
from t
group by (date2,GroupID)
having count(*) >1
```

Use this to identify records in main table that are duplicates:

```
Select *
from t
where date1='1900/01/01'
and (date2,groupID) = (Select date2,GroupID
                       from t
                       group by (date2,GroupID)
                       having count(*) >1)
```

NOTE: Since Date1, Date2, GroupID forms a unique key, check if your design is right in allowing Date1 to be NULL. You could have a genuine case where Date 1 is different for two rows while (date2,GroupID) is the same

Comment: Unfortunately I have to allow for the fact that there may be no information available for Date1

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a group of IDs for which GroupID and Date2 are the same, there's one occurance of Date1 that's different from 1900/01/01, and all the rest of the Date1s are 1900/01/01.

If I got it right, here's the query for you:

```
SELECT T.ID 
FROM Table T1
WHERE 

(T1.GroupID, T1.Date2) IN
    (SELECT T2.GroupID, T2.Date2
    WHERE T2.Date1 = '1900/01/01' OR
        T2.Date IS NULL
    GROUP BY T2.GroupID, T2.Date2)

AND 

1 >= 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM TABLE T3
    WHERE NOT (T3.Date1 = '1900/01/01') 
    AND NOT (T3.Date1 IS NULL)
    AND T3.GroupID = T1.GroupID
    AND T3.Date2 = T1.Date2
)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A check constraint perhaps.

Something along the lines of `select count(*) where date1 = '1900/01/01' and date2 = @date2 and groupid = @groupid`.

Just need to see if you can do this in a table-level constraint ....

Answer (score 0):

In addition to having a PRIMARY KEY field defined on the table, you can also add other UNIQUE constraints to perform the same sort of thing you're asking for. They'll validate that a particular column or set of columns have a unique value in the table.

Check out the entry in the MySQL manual for an example:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table a
join (
select Date2, GroupID, Count(*)
from table
group by Date2, GroupID
having count(*) > 1
) b on (a.Date2 = b.Date2 and a.GroupID = b.GroupID)
where a.Date1 = '1900/01/01'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most straightforward way I can think to do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM t t1 JOIN t t2 USING (date2, groupid)
WHERE t1.date1 = '1900/01/01';
```

No need to use `GROUP BY`, which performs poorly on some brands of database.